# meta_query on a date range using an array of values

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, mysql

How can I do a query to return the post if the custom field array contains a date that is within the specified range?
The query below is basically what I am after but it does not work...

```
// the income_dates array looks like this
// a:3:{i:0;s:10:"2014-02-01";i:1;s:10:"2014-03-01";i:2;s:10:"2014-03-29";}

$today = date("Y-m-d");
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . "-1 Month"));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . "+1 Month"));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'income',
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key' => 'income_dates',
            'value' => $date1,
            'type'  => 'date',
            'compare' => '>'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'income_dates',
            'value' => $date2,
            'type'  => 'date',
            'compare' => '<'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: If you need data comparison, you have to save the dates into multiple metas. Please refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) for the usage of `add_post_meta`.

Comment: Okay, I am already doing that. The income_dates custom field is holding the dates of recurring incomes and I thoight it would be better in an array otherwise the database might fill up pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to get post with type event and the custom field "date" later than today, this sample of code worked perfectly for me, I hope it helps to someone in a similar situation.

```
            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $today1 = date("Ymd", strtotime("$today"));
            $custom_meta = array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'data_de_inicio',
                    'value'=>$today1,
                    'compare'=>'>',
                    'type'=>'date',
                ),
            );
            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=>'event',
                'showposts'=>'3',
                'orderby'=>'meta_value',
                'meta_key'=>'data_de_inicio',
                'order'=>'asc',
                'meta_query'=>$custom_meta,
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest don't store the meta values as `array` because (I think) is not what you need. I think you really need to store each meta value individually with its own pair of key/value and not a single key with a serialized values. When done in this way, you can use the `BETWEEN` comparison:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
//'BETWEEN' comparison with 'type' date only works with dates in format YYYYMMDD.
//See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters 
$date1 = date("YYYYMMDD", strtotime($today . "-1 Month"));
$date2 = date("YYYYMMDD", strtotime($today . "+1 Month"));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'income',
    'meta_query' => array( 
     array(
         'key' => 'income_dates',
         'value' =>  array($date1,$date2),
         'type'  => 'date',
         'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
         ),
     )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yeah that would work but I would prefer to keep the dates in a single entry so I've just fetched all posts and using an if statement to get the results I'm after

Comment: @user537137 can you give an example of your code?

Comment: @AndrewWelch this was 3 years ago. Thanks for the interest but I don't even remember what this was for

Comment: I figured it out now, but the documentation for meta queries involving dates is a bit fragmented to say the least.